# Ruby: change directory

Tags: ruby

Current directory is `C:/Sites/todo` and I want to change it to `C:/Sites/todo/app/assets`. The problem is I need specify directory like `Dir.pwd("/app/assets")` but there is an error because I should write the whole path `C:/Sites/todo/app/assets`. How can I change directory with `/app/assets` path?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Write as below :

```
Dir.chdir(Dir.pwd+"/app/assets")
```

[`Dir::pwd`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Dir.html#method-c-pwd) *Returns the path to the current working directory of this process as a string.* Then [`Dir::chdir`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Dir.html#method-c-chdir) *Changes the current working directory of the process to the given string.* Remember if you are already in `C:/Sites/todo`, then only `Dir.chdir("app/assets")` will work.

One example to illustrate this :

```
irb(main):001:0> Dir.chdir('C:\Users\rakshiar')
=> 0
irb(main):002:0> Dir.pwd
=> "C:/Users/rakshiar"
irb(main):003:0> Dir.chdir('userdata\Tax form Demo')
=> 0
irb(main):004:0> Dir.pwd
=> "C:/Users/rakshiar/userdata/Tax form Demo"
irb(main):005:0>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'fileutils'

FileUtils.cd('app/assets')
```

Answer (score 1):

To change to app/assets from your application root:

```
Dir.chdir("app/assets")
```